# Salesforce 1 scrollbar not visible

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

This is an inline VFP with scrollbar (Desktop) but when I tried to view this in Salesforce 1, only the first 8 line item is visible with no scroll bar. Is this a bug or I need to add something?

this is the vfp

```
<apex:page standardController="Event" extensions="ext1" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false">
    <apex:form >
    <div style="margin:0px; overflow:auto">
      <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!list != null}">
         <div style="overflow:auto;"> 
          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!sublist}" var="s" rendered="{!sublist != null}" width="100%" styleClass="overflow:auto">
            <iframe scrolling="yes">   
              <apex:column headerValue="Activity">
                  <apex:outputField value="{!s.name}"/>
              </apex:column>
              </iframe>  
          </apex:pageBlockTable><br/>

          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!sList}" var="s" rendered="{!sList != null}">
              <apex:column headerValue="List">
                  <apex:outputLink value="/{!s.Id}" target="_parent">{!s.Name}</apex:outputLink>
              </apex:column>
          </apex:pageBlockTable>   
        </div>           
      </apex:pageBlock>
    </div>      
    </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Comment: Try with removing the custom css from your page - ‘overflow: auto;’

Comment: Hi, i removed it but it still not available on mobile